# IONIC self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to start my first app IONIC, 
after writing this cmd

`ionic start myapp blank`

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable did the trick for me.

You can set it using the command below, before you execute the ionic start command

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

or set in in your environment variables in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I found this was because the ports used by the ionic remote process were blocked by my corporate firewall.  Retrying whilst tethered to my iPhone 4G connection worked.